# JavaScript confirm(..) equivalent in Symfony PHP

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony, dialog

I'm using PHP framework Symfony 3, i have a simple form where the user can create a Sponsor object, when he submits that form i want a dialog (like confirm(..) with JavaScript) that is called after $em->flush() inside the controller that asks the user if he wants to create another Sponsor object, if he selects YES the form fields will be empty for him to create another, if he selects NO then he will be redirected to another page

How can i show a confirm() dialog before or after submitting the form so i can decide where to redirect the user ?

Comment: there is no equivalent to that, after flush you can return a view where user may choose to create another one

Comment: that's exactly what i'm trying to avoid, don't want extra views because that's extra loading time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony is a PHP Framework. So no you cannot do that with PHP.

One solution would be to add an hidden checkbox. When the submit button is hit, you can do a `confirm()` in JS and checked (or not) the checkbox. According the state of this checkbox you redirect your user to one page or another.

An other solution would be to add a visible checkbox and let the user decide when he fill the form.

An other solution would be to send the form async with JavaScript, so you can ask to your user whether or not he want to create a new Sponsor.

Comment: hidden checkbox solution seems nice, would something like this work :      < input type="submit" value="Create" onclick="function() { ('#myCheckBox')[0].checked = confirm("Create another ?")  } " / > and then in my controller i redirect the user according to the checkbox

Comment: Yes this should work.

Comment: ok thnaks a lot

Comment: i have a question, with that code, will the confirm(..) dialog show always or just when the form is validated ? i want it to show only when the form is validated

Comment: This will always be shown. Even if the form is not valid. But what does it matter ?You will check this input, then send the form. It won't be validated. So you'll have your errors for the user. He will correct the form, then resend the form, then ... etc.

Comment: that's a bit annoying but it works, but i couldn't get the value of the hidden checkbox, $form['myCheckBox']->getData() doesn't work, i want something that will return either true or false, my checkbox is a ChoiceType